# how to remove black bands that occur regularly in an image in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I've captured an image, and the image capture extension have left regular black bands that occur at regular intervals (see example below)

Is there an imagemagick command to remove all bands at once? I've tried to run it recursively, using the below pseudo-code, without success:

```
for i=1 to height of image/1000
split image at 1000 pixels * i
crop 10 pixels, top
stitch image with cropped image
```

EDIT: changed example image to a full resolution one

[image]

Comment: Post a full resolution version of the image.

Comment: done - ideally, I would be able to separate the individual slides as well, in addition to cropping

Comment: Your image looks like a screen snap. Do you not have an actual original image without the screen information and web site at the top, etc.  Why don't you just replace the black lines with white (background color of the slides).  You can also crop them equally if you want using -crop. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile

Comment: I think you can split out every section of white background with text from the black lines by thresholding and then using -connected-components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to crop each white section of your slides in ImageMagick 6 in Unix.

```
#
# threshold image
# use morphology to close up small black or white regions
# convert to bilevel
# do connected-component processing to find all regions larger than 1000 pixels in area
# keep only gray(255) i.e. white regions and get the bounding box and color and replace WxH+X+Y with W H X Y.
# sort by Y (rather than area) and put the x and +s back to re-form WxH+X+Y
# loop over data to get the bounding box and crop the image
# 

OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`convert slides.jpg -threshold 25% \
-morphology close rectangle:5 +write x1.png \
-morphology open rectangle:5  +write x2.png \
-type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=1000 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 y.png | grep "gray(255)" | sed 's/[x+]/ /g' | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}'`)
IFS=$OLD_IFS
num=${#arr[*]}
echo $num
echo "${arr[*]}"
# sort array by Y value
sortArr=(`echo "${arr[*]}" | sort -n -t " " -k4,4 | sed -n 's/^\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)$/\1x\2+\3+\4/p'`)
echo "${sortArr[*]}"
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
bbox="${sortArr[$i]}"
convert slides.jpg -crop $bbox +repage slides_section_$i.jpg
done
```

For Imagemagick 7, change "convert" to "magick"